# Вёрстка сайта из psd шаблонов

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Возник такой вопрос (по большей части проблема). Очень хочется научиться верстать сайты из psd шаблонов. С фш проблем нет,  там воплощаю в жизнь макет сайта, шаблон.  Но как его из psd сверстать сайт - нет опыта. Знание html и css есть. Дайте, пожалуйста, пару советов в этом деле. 
Может, ресурс какой-нибудь для прочтения подкиньте.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Расскажу как я делаю. Так же дам совет - не делай много лишнего, только нужное и удобное. В популярных сайтах нет лишнего, поэтому они удобные.

А так:

1. В фотошопе разбиваешь сайт по
           частям, по которым легче всего
           сколотить сайт.
2. Можно сохранять по отдельности каждый блок или элемент
       сайта в
           изображение, но рекомендуется все в
           один и уже из файла с помощью css
           вытаскивать нужные части.
3. После, с помощью CSS играешься с позиционированием блоков
       и верстаешь
           сайт через html.

Comment: а есть еще платные сервисы,которые по картинке тебе все с генерируют, правда платные. Да и если не ошибаюсь, в фш, когда-то был/есть функционал, который сам генерирует штмл и цсс... но, опять не уверен, только старым - табличным способом.

Answer (score 3):

Мой небольшой опыт.
Когда нарисовали сайт, вырезаете бэкграунды, кнопки и др. элементы сайта.
Если бэкграунд - паттерн, вырезайте квадрат размером 20х20, меньше не делайте.
Сохраняйте фалы для вэб.
Потом, когда все вырезано, начинаете писать html разметку не обращая внимания на css.
Соответственно вам надо уже знать, что и как будет у вас размечено.
Когда разметка есть начинате писать стили.
Отступы я лично мерю линейкой в фотошопе :). Получается довольно точно.
После верстки пишите js скрипты и если надо создаете отдельный стиль для internet explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Я тоже поделюсь своим небольшим опытом:

1. Планирование. Смотрите на psd и мысленно себе рисуете в голове как будут располагаться блоки, где будет картинка, а где можно шрифтом заменить, как лучше фон сделать т.д. Планировать можно (и нужно) и на бумаге. Там где сплошной цвет, можно залить цветом через CSS (и даже там где не сплошной можно). В общем правило первое: если где-то можно обойтись без картинок, не используйте картинки. Это касается и прозрачных блоков и закруглений и теней.
2. Раскройка. Берете ваш любимый режущий инструмент в фотошопе и аккуратно режете psd на те части, которые вы мысленно представляли себе при планировании. Сохранять можно в любые приемлемые форматы (главное, чтоб меньше весило при сохранении относительного качества).
3. Строите каркас из html. Здесь нужно вспомнить, что вы там напланировали и немного поправить верстку по ситуации.
4. А теперь самое главное. CSS. Здесь подходы могут быть разные, нужно выбрать оптимальный. Например, использовать ли reset.css и чем позиционировать: float-ом или position-ом. Или вообще таблицами где-то забацать. Главное правило: то, что можно сделать через CSS, делайте через CSS. Если возможностей CSS уже нехватает, оставляем это место для js.
5. Далее по желанию можно добавить интерактивности через js и сделать то, что не вышло через CSS. Ну и не забывайте постоянно тестировать страницу в различных браузерах.

Comment: Евгений Попов у него есть урок css уровень 2 если не ошибаюсь , я с этого и начинал понятно бесплатно и доходчива все объясняет